# Error by sending Konva. Collection by JQuery $.getJSON to Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, konvajs

I want to send coordinates of all rectangles on layer to my backend, so I'm using `var nodes = layer.find(".Rect")`, and this works fine for printing it (console.log(nodes)), but when I send it by jquery `$.getJSON` it breakes with error of KONVA `Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined konva konva.min.js:12/7 0.4`

```js
var nodes;
nodes = layer.find('.Rect')
$(function () {
    $('#save-template').bind('click', function () {
        $.getJSON('/_background_process', {
            squares: nodes,
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="save-template">Save</button>
```

```
def background_process():
    try:
        squares = request.args.get('squares')
        return jsonify(result="0")
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to save your array into plain objects first:

```js
const nodes = layer.find('.Rect');
const data = nodes.map(node => node.toObject());
```

Comment: Yeah, or string JSON.stringify(nodes)